# Make one recursive combined array from other arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, cartesian-product

I want to go from these arrays:

```
$array1 = ["x", "y", "z"];
$array2 = ["a","b"];
$array3 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"];
```

To this array:

```
$arrayResult = 
array(
    array("x" => array("a" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                       "b" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6)),
          "y" => array("a" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                       "b" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6)),
          "z" => array("a" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                       "b" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6)))
);
```

I tried to make this combined array with cartesian product approaches, but no satisfying result so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution without using any loop:

```
$array1 = ["x", "y", "z"];
$array2 = ["a","b"];
$array3 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"];

$result = array_combine(
    $array1, 
    array_fill(
        0, 
        count($array1), 
        array_combine(
            $array2, 
            array_fill(0, count($array2), $array3)
        )
    )
);

print_r($result);
```

Here is [the demo](https://eval.in/795047)

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
The complexity here is I don't know how many arrays will be provided to me.

It's more like :

    `$array1 = ["x", "y", "z"];`
    `$array2 = ["a","b"];`
    `$array3 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"];`
    `$arrayN...`

Answer (score 0):

use array_fill_keys twice to get the result

```
$result = array_fill_keys(
              $array1, 
              array_fill_keys($array2,  $array3)
);
```

**[Demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/795099)**